# Get hashMessage in Java/Kotlin same like in solidity

Tags: java, kotlin, solidity, smartcontracts, web3-java

I need a function (Java/Kotlin) that returns hashMessage which corresponds to Solidity function:

```
function getMessageHash(address _signer, uint _amount, uint _id) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_signer, _amount, _id));
}
```

This function should return value of format: hash = "0xcf36ac4f97dc10d91fc2cbb20d718e94a8cbfe0f82eaedc6a4aa38946fb797cd"

I've tried using **Hash.sha3(String hexInput)**. from the org.web3j.crypto.Hash package but it only accepts one parameter.
I can't figure out what does abi.encodePacked() is doing with parameters under the "hood".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found the solution, so I'll post it here if anyone needs it.
The main question was, what is the `abi.encodePacked()` method doing "under the hood".

[HERE](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.3/abi-spec.html#non-standard-packed-mode) is a detailed explanation how some of the parameters are encoded in this method.

For the particular question and method with next parameters:
`encodedMessage = abi.encodePacked("0x1b77882d1e55ffff0bc1c4215b869a2a36f7054d", 1, 1)` the result from this method is:
encodedMessage = 1b77882d1e55ffff0bc1c4215b869a2a36f7054d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001

For the **_signer** (`string`) the prefix (`0x`) was removed, for **_amount** and **_id** (`uint`) I used `TypeEncoder.encode(Uint256(1))`.
Encoded values for each parameter is appended to the previous one, and at last hashed together with method: `val hashedMessage = Hash.sha3(encodedMessage)` which result is: **0xe06176482c2b2619110be196a3d999dedf922782c0fe85603b19044bf30b3856**

Later on **hashedMessage** can be used for signing or verification of signature. But that is out of the scope of this question.